# How to Configure Private Routes in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt

I have Created an AuthContext in my React application where AuthProvider has an method called isAuthenticated and login.

I am simply storing access token and refresh token in the localStorage when user login and whenever any Component is called it checked weather the user is authenticated or not. Here I am redirecting the User after it is Authenticated to "/Home" Route but I don't know where I am wrong but every time i get redirected to Login Page.

AuthContent Login Method:

```
const LoginSucess=axios.post('/login',{            
  username,            
  password          
}).then(function(response){            
  console.log(response);            
  setUser(response.data)            
  if(response.status===200){                
    localStorage.setItem("token",JSON.stringify(response.data));                
    return true;                
    // return redirect("/Home");            
  }          
}).catch(function(error){            
  console.log(error);            
  return false;          
})                    
return LoginSucess;                  
} catch (error) {          
  console.error('Authentication failed:', error.message);          
  throw error;        
}
```

isAuthenticated Method:

```
 const isAuthenticated = async() => {
      if(user.accessToken){
        const decodedToken = jwtDecode(user.accessToken);
        const currentTimestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

        if (decodedToken.exp && currentTimestamp > decodedToken.exp) {
          console.error('JWT has expired');
          const accessToken=await axios.post('/token',{
            username:decodedToken.name,
            token:user.refreshToken
            
          }).then(function(response){
            console.log("ans ",response);
            const intialToken=user;
            intialToken.accessToken=response.data.accessToken;
            localStorage.setItem("token",JSON.stringify(intialToken));
            setUser(intialToken);
            return true;

          }).catch(function(error){
            console.log("Error ",error);
            return false;
          })
          
          

          return accessToken;
        } else {
          console.log('JWT is valid');
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
```

Private Routes Menthod:

```
export default function PrivateRoutes() {    
  const {isAuthenticated}=useAuth();    
  const [ans, setAns] = useState(undefined);    
  useEffect(()=>{        
    async function checkAuthenticated(){            
      isAuthenticated()            
        .then(result => {              
        setAns(result);              
        console.log('Authentication result:', result);            
      })            
        .catch(error => {              
        console.error('Error checking authentication:', error);              
        setAns(false);             });        
    }        checkAuthenticated();    
  },[])    
  useEffect(() => {        
    console.log('ans after useEffect:', ans);      
  }, [ans]);    
  console.log("Private Route ",ans);    
  return (        
    ans ? <Outlet/> : <Navigate to="/login" />    
  )
}
```